# Handle predefined tags cloud / labels on mongo

Tags: mongodb, nosql, tags, label, microservices

I have a nosql db(mongo) that looks like (list of events):

```
[  {
   "_id" : ObjectId("4......),
   "title" : test",
   "content" : "testtest",
   "tags" : [
       {
           "name" : "meta",
           "Pinned" : true
       },
       {
           "name" : "post",
           "Pinned" : false
       },
   ]
}]
```

Now i am looking to way how to implement new logic as follows:

- i need a predefined tags that always be available in each scans
- user can remove/add custom  tag  and pin tag (toggle click) per evens
- if tag is pinned the next event that will appear will keep the existing list

So my quesions are :
How to Implement the way that i need to keep the state of the pinned tag (even if its a new tag that added to the latest event).
I thought to create another collection (in the same db under same microservice) to hold the current list in every change.

- is the structure for the tags it self is ok ?